# Delete last decimal value in a double

Tags: c#, math, calculator

I am making a calculator in C#.
I save the input from the user as a double.

I use the following code to delete the last entered number in a double withour decimals.

```
i = (i - (i % 10)) / 10;
```

This wil delete the last number.

12345 wil become 1234

What I can't figuere out is how to make this happen for decimal values.

2134.765 must become 2134.76

my program uses a var to see if a point has been put in so I only need the math to delete the last number.

Comment: Are you sure you want your calculator to operate on a double, as opposed to a decimal? Anyway you could keep a variable that contains the number of digits to display.

Comment: For doubles you can use Math.Round.  Why would you want to truncate an integer though, ie 12345?

Comment: It's for the backspace button.
So that is why it needs to delete the last number.

Comment: Tinkering with the value is a big mistake, floating point math is not accurate enough to generate a value that you'll like consistently.  Focus on the *presentation*, not the value.  I'll ignore your attempt at getting rounding wrong and recommend: Dim displayString = value.ToString("N2").  If you want to continue calculating with the displayed value instead of the actual value then just use the Parse() method.

Comment: While having dialog with user work with `string`. Then `parse` into `decimal`, `double` and compute the result.

Comment: `i= i / 10` is enough to remove the last digit !

Comment: @Yves no, that can cause rounding issues (because of math, because of the last digit being 5-9 and because of floating point math). Backspacing `15` will yield `2`, and backspacing `1.123` can yield `0.11229999999` if you simply divide by 10.

Comment: @CodeCaster: right, I was assuming integers. I wonder if the OP's formula works in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're dealing with *character* input and not *math* yet, just keep your input as a string *until you need to perform an operation on it*.   Then removing the last character is as simple as

```
input = input.Substring(0,input.Length-1);
```

Otherwise you have to deal with ambiguous situations like:

- What if the last character is a decimal point?
- What if one or more trailing zeros have been entered?
- Has a decimal point been entered (you say you already track this)

Comment: I might indeed have to do this.
thought it might be nice to keep everything as math, but I am indeed getting a lot of trouble with that :(

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to use your own number format - you want to keep the values decimal anyway. `double` is a terrible choice for that. At the very least, use a `decimal` so that you're *guaranteed* the decimal representation of the number.

Answer (score 0):

If you really always only wanna delete the last digit in the number I would use a trick and convert the number to string remove the last char and back.

```
var number = 123,456;
var strNumber = number;
strNumber.Remove(strNumber.Length - 1);
number = double.parse(strNumber);
```

Comment: var strNumber = number; - what type do you expect "strNumber" to be here? Thank you for this because it's the perfect example of why you should never use var.